# how to ignore a native error IOS react native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

How can i take the responsibility of native exceptions and don't let the app crash on release mode ?

**the app continue working fine after dismissing this propmt.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can handle exceptions and errors in your entire app by wrapping it inside an Error Boundary. From the official React docs:

> Error boundaries are React components that catch JavaScript errors
> anywhere in their child component tree, log those errors, and display
> a fallback UI instead of the component tree that crashed.

[Read more about error boundaries and how to use them here (Official React documentation).](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)

Comment: the error i am getting is the native IOS exception error, does it also can handle it?
i mean it is not JSbundle error

Comment: @AmirDoreh Oh, then maybe this library can help [react-native-exception-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-exception-handler). It was made to handle native exceptions.

Comment: i am already using that , it is not working